# expensive aws load balancer, perhaps wrong setup

Tags: socket.io, amazon-elb

Some time ago, I needed HTTPS support for my express webserver. I found a tutorial that teached me a cool trick to achieve this. They basically explained me that an AWS load balancer can redirect HTTPS to HTTP.

So, I first created a load balancer.

[image: type of load balancer]

And then **redirected HTTPS to HTTP**. The traditional HTTP, I just redirected 80 to 80. And I have a websocket (socket io) thing going on port 1337 (which I plan to change to port 1338 in the near future).

[image: configured redirections]

Just for clarity. I didn't really need a load balancer, since **I actually only have 1 AWS instance**. But using this setup, I did not have to go through the trouble of messing around with HTTPS certificate files, neither did I have to upgrade my webserver. It saved me a lot of trouble at first.

Then this morning, I received the bill, and discovered that this load balancing trick has a price tag of roughly 22usd/mo. (**an expensive port forwarding trick**)

[image: billing]

I probably have to get rid of this load balancer. But I am wondering, perhaps I did something wrong in the configuration.

It's strange that charges are so high for a web app that is still in development. So, I am wondering if perhaps there is something wrong with my setup. And that leads me to the following question.

I noticed that **I am actually using an old ELB setup**: **"Classic load balancer"**. And it actually states that this setup does not support websockets, which is a bit strange.

[image: differences]

My web app hosts some static webpages (angular), but once it is downloaded, **all traffic uses socket.io websockets**. Even though the AWS documentation says that websockets are not supported, it seems to work fine. Unless ...

Now, socket io is a pretty smart thing. When it can't use modern websockets (e.g. because the webbrowser does not support it), it falls back to a kind of **HTTP polling**. I guess that means that from a load-balancer point of view, it creates 100s of visits per minute. And right now, I am wondering if that has an influence on the charges.

My really long question comes down to a simple one. **Do you think upgrading my load balancer would decrease the number of counted "loadbalancer hours" ?**

## EDIT

Here are some ELB metrics. They are too complicated for me to draw conclusions. But perhaps some of you experts can. :)

[image: metrics]

Comment: If your going only for https: why not use letsencrypt. its free and really easy to use. it will even inject the settings into your web server and can even auto rotate your certs every 3 months.

https://letsencrypt.org/

Edit: more info

Comment: I actually did that for my other non-aws webservers and it worked fine. That's certainly a good long-term solution. But it feels a bit wasteful that AWS actually provides me with free amazon certificates, which seem more trustworthy than letsencrypt. So, I'm tempted to get AWS certificates working in the long run. Just a lot of work right now. :) and the bill is counting.

Comment: so as Amazon and LetsEncrpt are both non verified certs there is the same level of trust. if you want to be trusted you need to invest in a vetted cert like an EV cert,

Comment: @JoshBeauregard The approach of using ELB is better for two reasons. First, it is technology-agnostic which can be a huge plus when working with selfmade or bleeding edge technology. Second, you can debug requests more easily (unencrypted once reaching the server) and scale up to multiple instances without a hassle.

Comment: @JoshBeauregard Of course Amazon provides valid certificates for public domains.

Comment: So, I would say the answer to this is simple: If you have a load balancer running 24/7 - as it is usual with web servers - this price is to be expected. To be honest - I think it's fair for what it can do. It provides your certificate, but also decrypts HTTPS to HTTP at really good performance. Not to speak of it's ability to - well- actually load balance.

Comment: @MarkusAppel I agree that it is worth the money if it is put to good use. But if the loadbalancer is multiple times more expensive than the total costs of all envolved instances, then something is wrong. Either the pricing scales badly or there is something wrong with my setup. --> if the setup is fine, then I have to find an alternative, which is unfortunate for the time spend.

Comment: @bvdb Looking at the numbers I would say that your setup is fine - given that your webserver has to actually constantly handle requests and is never idle.